# Deploy Adobe AIR app in to iOS simulator

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, adobe, ios-simulator

I'm trying to run a simple test app on a iOS simulator but I'm getting this error:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
java.io.IOException: PLIST generation failed due to SAX error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
  at com.adobe.air.Plist.newFromString(Plist.java:351)
  at com.adobe.air.Plist.newFromFile(Plist.java:325)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.setSDKVersion(IPAOutputStream.java:1070)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.setPlatformSDKLocation(IPAOutputStream.java:971)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.setDeviceSDKDirectory(IPAPackager.java:187)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseFileAndPathArguments(ADT.java:1423)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseDescriptorAndFileset(ADT.java:1474)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseInput(ADT.java:929)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.parsePackage(ADT.java:672)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:570)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:419)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:469)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unable to find llvm JNI lib in:
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib/adt.jar/Darwin
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib/aot/lib/x64
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib/adt.jar
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/lib

  at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.loadJNI(LLVMEmitter.java:582)
  at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.<clinit>(LLVMEmitter.java:596)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.generateExtensionsGlue(AOTCompiler.java:419)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.generateMachineBinaries(AOTCompiler.java:1790)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.createIosBinary(IPAOutputStream.java:378)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.finalizeSig(IPAOutputStream.java:743)
  at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.createPackage(ApplicationPackager.java:91)
  at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.createPackage(IPAPackager.java:245)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:571)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:419)
  at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:469)
```

I've google it and I was not able to fix it.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an ActionScriptMobileProject
2. Configure it to run on iOS simulator
3. Run it without any change in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue we need to update the AIR SDK

https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html

Copy it here:

- Mac OS X: `/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK`
- Windows 7 (64-Bit): `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK`

and update the *-app.xml file header to this one:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0">
```

See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html